# Stored procedure hangs on statement.execute()

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why would a Snowflake stored procedure hang on a statement that, when executed outside the stored procedure, works? Further info: I remove that statement from the stored procedure, then the SP also runs properly. How can this sort of thing be debugged?

(One more piece of info: running as a different user on a different schema, the SP works as intended.)

Update: running the SP on a different warehouse worked, so it might be a problem with the warehouse, not the schema.

Comment: It could be great if you add some piece of code or error msg of your code.

Comment: The SP was pretty unremarkable (`select count(...)` from a table, and writing it out to a stage). And since it just hangs, there are no error messages or codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would a Snowflake stored procedure hang on a statement that, when executed outside the stored procedure, works?

There can be multiple reasons: Query gets queued due to lack of resources, is awaiting a lock to free (if its a transactional query), etc.

> How can this sort of thing be debugged?

Check the Query History UI page on Snowflake. If your procedure-executed statement is showing a [queued status](https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/how-to-diagnose-a-slow-running-query), you're likely running into a [warehouse size limit or a maximum concurrency limit](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Understanding-Queuing), which can be resolved by reconfiguring your warehouse (via [auto-scaling](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-multicluster.html) and/or using higher warehouse sizes).

Comment: Thx, that helped. It does seem to be a problem with warehouses resources. The SP shows up as `running`, but the sub-procedure (`statement.execute...`) shows up as `blocked`. AHA, there was something wrong with MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL --- it was set to 1. That explains it, thanks again!